# Inflated View doesn't catch onClick event

Tags: android, onclick, android-inflate

I have an template view it looks like ;

template.xml :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/contentLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/view_background"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnMultiple"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/button_backgroundblue"
    android:onClick="btnMultiple_clicked"
    android:tag="4"
    android:text="@string/mc_abcd"
    android:textColor="@drawable/button_textcolor"
    android:textSize="@dimen/h2" />
```

I'm creating this view programmatically and then i'm adding this View into ViewFlipper as like ;

activity_main.java

```
public void btnCreateView_clicked(View view) {
    ViewFlipper viewFlipper = (ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.flipper);

    View myView = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.template, viewFlipper, false);
    viewFlipper.addView(myView);
    viewFlipper.showNext(); // Showing lastly created myView successfully. }
```

Also my activity has public function as like ;

activity_main.java

```
    public void btnMultiple_clicked(View view) {
        //Save the world !
}
```

When i press btnCreateView button from first view it's successfully creating template (myView) and then adding it into ViewFlipper. When i click btnMultiple i'm getting error and my application crashes ; "Could not find a method btnMultiple_clicked(View) in the activity class android.app.Application for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'btnMultiple'" i'm sure there is existing method btnMultiple_clicked(View).

PS! If i add listener to btnMultiple programmatically it's gonna work but i wonder why "android:onClick="btnMultiple_clicked"" doesn't work ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Android looks for the method defined in the `onClick` attribute in the `Activity`. The problem in your code is that you used for the `LayoutInflater` initialization the `Application`'s `Context` and not the `Context` of the `Activity` so the method will not be found there(the `Context` is passed to the `View`). Use:

```
View myView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.template, viewFlipper, false);
```

or any other reference that points to the `Activity` where those buttons will be used.
This is a good example why you should use in most cases the `Context` of the `Activity`.